# javascript not running but working when I type on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

So I made the a .js file that has the connect4 game which works
Then I made another js file to check for the win condition in that connect 4 game
When I run the code in the console it works but does not work otherwise.
I checked if it is linked by using the script to type in console and it works.

The code is as follows :

```
var j = 0
if ($('.col1').eq(j).css('background-color') == $('.col1').eq(j+1).css('background-color') && $('.col1').eq(j+1).css('background-color') == $('.col1').eq(j+2).css('background-color') && $('.col1').eq(j+2).css('background-color') == $('.col1').eq(j+3).css('background-color') && $('.col1').eq(j).css('background-color') == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
  $('h4').text(name1 + ' has won the game!')
}
```

Comment: Where is this code in relation to the rest of your code?  From your comments, looks like it's running when the page loads rather than after a move.

Comment: Note that `.css("background-color")` may output in a different format based on the browser, better to add/remove a class and check for that class

Comment: in the html document I have placed the script below

Comment: It needs to be run after every time a player makes a move

Comment: how would i go on doing that?

Comment: my first js file has .click() that is where I change colors when the person clicks on a specific column

Comment: Yes, after you change the colours

Comment: Oh!!! I got it. Sorry I have just started learning. my bad!